# Error when trying to install discord module using pip

Tags: python

I am attempting to download the `discord.py` module using `pip`, but I keep getting a syntax error like this:

```
>>> py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I made sure `pip` was installed and tried downloading the module from the `.whl` file directly only to receive a syntax error in the same place.

Comment: you're supposed to use `pip` from the command line, not in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running the command in the Python REPL interpreter. You should run that command in the terminal/CLI of the operating system.

Comment: "That's the one in black, right?" You mean terminal/CLI? What Operating System you are on?

Comment: @cr725 No, you re not. You are clearly inside the REPL

Comment: Oh I see how I misunderstood, I didn't read close enough. Thank you!